# Style property won't update unless there is a math operation

Tags: reactjs

I have encountered a weird situation in React 15/16 where style properties won't update unless there is a mathematical operation, even though the property is updated in scope. In the example below, I am updating the `size` property forcing the component to rerender.

```js
function MyComponent(props) {
  const { size } = props;

  const styles = {
    width: size,  <-- this won't update in the DOM, even though size changes
    borderWidth: size * 0.1, <-- this does update
  }

  console.log('size =', size, styles);

  return <div style={styles} />;
}
```

Output:

```
size = 30 {
  "width": "30",
  "borderWidth": 3
}

size = 33 {
  "width": "33",
  "borderWidth": 3.30
}
```

Yet, in the DOM the `style="width"` attribute is unchanged, but the `borderWidth` property is correct.

I've resorted to multiplying all the props by 1 to deal with this, but that is just stupid.

Seems like a bug? Is there a "correct" way to deal with this?

Comment: You are doing something wrong then somewhere else, It works properly , check the working demo https://codesandbox.io/s/4rp33x8y70,

Comment: simply.. add `px` to your `30` string or convert your `30` string to a number using `Number` and send it in styles. Then react will handle it appropriately for you. :-) If you understand it,, good :)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, Hmm... let me look at your demo and compare to my code some more. This is odd.

Comment: the size value is probably a string, try this `width: +size`. I am thinking `"30" * .1` updates because the result is a number.

Answer (score 0):

According to [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html),

> React will automatically append a “px” suffix to certain numeric inline style properties. If you want to use units other than “px”, specify the value as a string with the desired unit.

So in your case, if you want to set the width as 30px, you should write it as either `30` or `'30px'`.

Also, it may have been a typo here:

```
return <div style={style} />;
```

it should be `<div style={styles} />` (you missed `s`)

What you logged is `styles`, but what you passed as prop is `style`.

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer, but this is not what I am asking. I have edited the question to clarify. I am changing the size property and only some of the styles are updating (the ones with mathematical operations).

Comment: @James Updated my answer. Perhaps it was the typo?